# Catch pyautogui.FailSafeException whilst program is waiting to execute next line of code

Tags: python, time, sleep, pyautogui

I am using `pyautogui` inside an infinite while loop to iteratively move my mouse around the screen every 10 seconds. `pyautogui` implements a failsafe, which throws `pyautogui.FailSafeException` if the mouse is in the top left corner of the screen - (0, 0) coordinates.

I implement this simple logic using `time.sleep()` and the following code:

```
import time 

try:
    while True:
        for coords in [(100, 100), (1000, 100), (1000, 1000), (100, 1000)]:
            pyautogui.moveTo(coords)
            time.sleep(10)  # <- I want to be catching exceptions during this time period as well as when the code is actively running 
except pyautogui.FailSafeException:
    # DO SOMETHING
```

However, if I move my mouse to the top left corner during the 10 seconds of sleep, the exception does not get caught until the 10 seconds of sleep are over (obviously!). My goal is to immediately catch this exception, rather than having to wait until the end of these 10 seconds.

So my question is - is there a function that will allow me to catch exceptions whilst the code is "doing nothing" for 10 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can poll to check if the time has expired rather than use a blocking sleep command. While polling, you can check the position of the mouse. If the position of the mouse is `(0,0)` you can then break out instantly.

Here is the code:

#### Code:

```
import time 
import pyautogui

def sleep_for(secs):
    current_time = time.time()
    end_time = time.time() + secs
    
    while current_time < end_time:
        current_time = time.time()
        if pyautogui.position() == (0,0):
            print("Fail Safe Exit")
            break
     
try:
    while True:
        for coords in [(100, 100), (1000, 100), (1000, 1000), (100, 1000)]:
            pyautogui.moveTo(coords)
            sleep_for(10) 
                
             
except pyautogui.FailSafeException:
    # DO SOMETHING
    pass
```

The `sleep_for()` function is used to monitor the mouse position while waiting for 10 seconds. If the mouse moves to position `(0,0)` then it will break out of the while loop instantly.